# Should this be a namespace or a class?

Tags: c++, coding-style

When you have a set of functions that have no interaction between them, you place them in a namespace. (Example, a `math` namespace.)

When you have some public attributes and optionally a set of functions that act on those attributes, that should become a class.

But what about when you have a set of related functions but no public attributes? An example would be an event manager: you might only have `subscribe()`, `post()`, and `dispatch()` and no public attributes; however you do have hidden attributes like a list of subscribers and an event queue that the three functions act upon. Should this be a class or a namespace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any time you have behavior and state it should be a class, even if the state isn't publicly accessible. One practical reason for this is it makes it easier to unit test other modules that interact with the module in question.

Answer (score 2):

A class. You have a state, albeit internal, so you may want to create two event managers (two queues).

Answer (score 2):

This should definitely be class, because it has internal state. What if you need more than one instance? In that case namespace can't help you, and class can.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create one of more instances of the thing that each have a lifetime, then it should be a class.

An event manager sounds like something you want to create, use and then destroy. So, it should be a class.

namespaces were only really introduced to help with very large programs. In a large program you may have multiple teams of developers each writing code. It may not be feasible for each team to make sure that nobody else uses happens to give a function or class the same name as somebody else. Or, names of things may clash with 3rd party libraries that might want to be used. Namespaces help avoid these problems. If you're not working on a huge project, you probably don't really need to bother ever using namespaces for your own code, unless you feel the need to organize your code into a few namespaces just to keep it neat. Using unnecessarily small namespaces can make code painful to work with. There's not much point in over obsessing about whether code should be in this namespace or that one, it's better to focus on making sure the code actually works.